# C code waits for more inputs instead of printing error

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that takes user input    . If the types aren't specified by the user, then there should be all 3 values like:
0 1 2
and the program defaults to a specific type format.
It has to have all 3 values to be a valid input, if less than 3 values are entered it should return an error message. 
The problem I'm having is if I enter less than 3 values, the program clearly just waits for the rest of the inputs. How do I go about making it move on to the error message if the user just enters 0,1 or 2 values and presses enter?
Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
if (actuallyTypes) {
    scanf("%s", initialCheck);
    scanf("%s", finalCheck);
    scanf("%s", intermediateCheck);
} else {
    scanf(input, "%s", initialCheck);
    scanf("%s", finalCheck);
    scanf("%s", intermediateCheck);    
}
```

And then I have an assert function checking whether inputs are valid or not, and if not it prints the error message.

Comment: Are you providing the input as a single line separated with spaces?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and **use the debugger**. [pseudoterminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) and [terminal emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) are complex stuff and operating system specific

Comment: On what operating system? Did you carefully read documentation of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)? Show also the rest of your code!

Comment: `scanf(input, "%s", initialCheck);` is wrong

Comment: You need to respond to the comment by @J...S . If your input is all on one line, just read the line into a buffer and parse the number of tokens with either `sscanf` or `strtok`. Your other option is to use `select` (or one of its variants) with a timeout option and take some default action if there is no input file description ready within the timeout period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with fgets() to extract the number of inputs in the string and logic in the assert function to make sure it's that number of inputs.

Answer (score -2):

Use just one `scanf` instead of three. Example:

```
scanf("%s %s %s", initialCheck,finalCheck,intermediateCheck)
```

Comment: What's the `%S` for?

Comment: doing so further breaks the program, and makes it print the error message when it isn't supposed to and it now waits for two lines of 3 value input

Comment: The `%S` should be `%s` and the result (counter) of `scanf` should be tested